# Problems turning API call into dataframe

Tags: r, api, dataframe, rjson

i want to create a dataframe out of an API call from the comtrade database. 
The comtrade database provides this code on it's side. Modifying it for my parameters however doesn't yield the wished outout.

The code looks like this:

```
library("rjson")
string <- get.Comtrade(px = "HS", ps = "2002" , p = "124" , r = "842" , fmt = "json")
reporters <- fromJSON(file = string)
reporters <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(reporters$results,rbind)))

get.Comtrade <- function(url = "http://comtrade.un.org/api/get?"
                         ,maxrec = 50000
                         ,type = "C"
                         ,freq = "A"
                         ,px = "HS"
                         ,ps = "now"
                         ,r = ""
                         ,p = ""
                         ,rg = "all"
                         ,cc = "TOTAL"
                         ,fmt = "json") {
  string <- paste(
    url
    ,"max=",maxrec,"&" #maximum no. of records returned
    ,"type=",type,"&" #type of trade (c=commodities)
    ,"freq=",freq,"&" #frequency
    ,"px=",px,"&" #classification
    ,"ps=",ps,"&" #time period
    ,"r=",r,"&" #reporting area
    ,"p=",p,"&" #partner country
    ,"rg=",rg,"&" #trade flow
    ,"cc=",cc,"&" #classification code
    ,"fmt=",fmt        #Format
    ,sep = ""
  )

  if (fmt == "csv") {
    raw.data <- read.csv(string,header = TRUE)
    return(list(validation = NULL, data = raw.data))
  } else {
    if (fmt == "json") {
      raw.data <- fromJSON(file = string)
      data <- raw.data$dataset
      validation <- unlist(raw.data$validation, recursive = TRUE)
      ndata <- NULL
      if (length(data) > 0) {
        var.names <- names(data[[1]])
        data <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(data,rbind)))
        ndata <- NULL
        for (i in 1:ncol(data)) {
          data[sapply(data[,i],is.null),i] <- NA
          ndata <- cbind(ndata, unlist(data[,i]))
        }
        ndata <- as.data.frame(ndata)
        colnames(ndata) <- var.names
      }
      return(list(validation = validation,data = ndata))
    }
  }
}
```

However, executing the code results in two errors:

```
 reporters <- fromJSON(file=string)
 Error in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) : 'con' is not a connection
 reporters <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(reporters$results,rbind)))
 Error in reporters$results : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

and string contains the following information:

```
 List of 2
 $ validation: Named chr [1:12] "Ok" "0" "0" "" ...
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12] "status.name" "status.value"       "status.category" "status.description" ...
 $ data      :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  35 variables:
 ..$ pfCode       : Factor w/ 1 level "H2": 1 1 1
 ..$ yr           : Factor w/ 1 level "2002": 1 1 1
 ..$ period       : Factor w/ 1 level "2002": 1 1 1
 ..$ periodDesc   : Factor w/ 1 level "2002": 1 1 1
 ..$ aggrLevel    : Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 ..$ IsLeaf       : Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 ..$ rgCode       : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
 ..$ rgDesc       : Factor w/ 3 levels "Export","Import",..: 2 1 3
 ..$ rtCode       : Factor w/ 1 level "842": 1 1 1
 ..$ rtTitle      : Factor w/ 1 level "USA": 1 1 1
 ..$ rt3ISO       : Factor w/ 1 level "USA": 1 1 1
 ..$ ptCode       : Factor w/ 1 level "124": 1 1 1
 ..$ ptTitle      : Factor w/ 1 level "Canada": 1 1 1
 ..$ pt3ISO       : Factor w/ 1 level "CAN": 1 1 1
 ..$ ptCode2      : Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA
 ..$ ptTitle2     : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1
 ..$ pt3ISO2      : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1
 ..$ cstCode      : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1
 ..$ cstDesc      : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1
 ..$ motCode      : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1
 ..$ motDesc      : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1
 ..$ cmdCode      : Factor w/ 1 level "TOTAL": 1 1 1
 ..$ cmdDescE     : Factor w/ 1 level "ALL COMMODITIES": 1 1 1
 ..$ qtCode       : Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1
 ..$ qtDesc       : Factor w/ 1 level "No Quantity": 1 1 1
 ..$ qtAltCode    : Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA
 ..$ qtAltDesc    : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1
 ..$ TradeQuantity: Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA
 ..$ AltQuantity  : Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA
 ..$ NetWeight    : Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA
 ..$ GrossWeight  : Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA
 ..$ TradeValue   : Factor w/ 3 levels "160794797453",..: 3 1 2
 ..$ CIFValue     : Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA
 ..$ FOBValue     : Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA
 ..$ estCode      : Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
```

Any type of help recommended and honoured with good karma,

Best regards, Sara

Comment: `string <- get.Comtrade(px = "HS", ps = "2002" , p = "124" , r = "842" , fmt = "json");
reporters <- fromJSON(file = string)` <- you're asking fromJSON to read as a file the output of your get.Comtrade function, as your function return a list it's probably your main problem.

Comment: Well i actually copied this from the Comtrade Side and trusted it to work. Do you know how to solve my problem?

Comment: Did you copy the whole script or only the function ?

Comment: It seems it's buggy in this case (or they changed the json format without updating the example script) :) I assume you're looking to only the output of the function (I.e the `string` variable). As you don't say what you're aiming to do with these data, I can't give more advice

Comment: Well the goal is to get a dataframe that yields bilateral tradeflows of countries by product classifications. It produces this string variable, but doesn't transform it into a data matrix

Comment: Unsure but is not `string[['data']]` what you're looking for ?

Comment: No, that 'tabulates' the data in the console. What i want to have is to transform the 'value' string into 'data' that appear in the environment above (i use R-Studio) to work with it. You know what i mean?

Comment: Absolutely not, sorry. Just hope you're not asking for `data <- string[['data']]`

Comment: Unfortunately that was exactly what i needed :) one further question: is it possible to write the get.comtrade function, that draw the data from the comtrade side, into a loop that downloads and composes the data? Requests are limited to 50000 records per query and i'd like to bypass this restriction ..

Comment: If basic assignment don't come to your mind at first glance, start by reading a R tutorial before trying to go further or you'll bang your head on the wall really soon.

Comment: @Tensibai [The Help Vampire problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665)

Comment: @BhargavRao I know it, but still try to educate (to a certain extend) ;)

Comment: @Tensibai Perhaps this is why they've added a close reason :D

Comment: @BhargavRao Turn out it becomes too broad by comments, at first it's a real code problem. I kind of disagree on closing, does not worth a downvote as it's a well formed Q with mcve, may be of use to someone else hanging with this API service example. Only my opinion, etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the string should be assigned as:

```
    string <- "http://comtrade.un.org/data/cache/reporterAreas.json"
```

and at the end of the function request for the data as:

```
    data<-get.Comtrade(px = "HS", ps = "2002" , p = "124" , r = "842" , fmt = "json")
```